# How to use a resource data value in two places in XAML?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I would like to have the same text displayed as the tooltip for a `Button` and as the text of a `TextBlock`.  Here's my simplified xaml:

```
<Button x:Uid="SweetButton">
  <TextBlock x:Uid="SweetTextBlock"/>
</Button>
```

Right now I have two entries in my .resw file:

```
<data name="SweetButton.ToolTipService.ToolTip" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>The same text</value>
</data>
<data name="SweetTextBlock.Text" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>The same text</value>
</data>
```

Is there any way for me to only have one entry in my .resw file?

I've tried giving the data element two name attributes, but that's not allowed.  I thought of somehow referencing the value of one data element as the value of the second data element, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't re-use that resource entry while still using the `x:Uid` syntax as you're trying to fill in 2 complete different properties (`ToolTip` and `Text`). The universal resource system with `x:Uid` is very powerful and can have about any attached property in your resource file, but the downside is repeatability of resource values.

> UWP XAML has somewhat different rules for x:Uid uniqueness than previous XAML-utilizing technologies used. For UWP XAML it is legal for the same x:Uid ID value to exist as a directive on multiple XAML elements. However, each such element must then share the same resolution logic when resolving the resources in a resource file. Also, all XAML files in a project share a single resource scope for purposes of x:Uid resolution, there is no concept of x:Uid scopes being aligned to individual XAML files.

*Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204791.aspx*

If you have a lot of duplicate resource values, you could consider using one of the 'old' ways to handle resources and bind the resources yourself.